# A term for a binary matrix that represents paths in a tree

Tags: matrices, terminology, trees

Is there a term for a 0-1 matrix whose rows correspond to the paths from root to leaf in a tree?

An example of such a matrix is:

```
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 1
```

It corresponds to the tree:

```
1 
|-- 2
|-- 3 
    |--4
    |--5
       |--6
```

There is a root (1) and three leaves (2, 4, 6) and each row in the matrix corresponds to a path from the root to one of these leaves.

Answer (score 0):

Such matrix is called the *ancestor matrix* of a binary tree.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://www.ritambhara.in/build-binary-tree-from-ancestor-matrics/  It looks similar but not identical.